# sender non-delivery notification while sending the email

Tags: shell, email, gmail

this is the command i am trying to send the email from command line.

```
 echo "Test Email message body" | mail -s "Email test subject" sampleemail971@gmail.com
```

this is error i am getting while sending the mail. It shows mail has delivered but in mail i didn't receive any email.please help to send the email in postfix

```
Apr 20 15:52:42 igslt14-HP-Notebook postfix/pickup[25694]: 8FDABE20E93: uid=1000 from=<igs-lt14@igslt14-HP-Notebook>
Apr 20 15:52:42 igslt14-HP-Notebook postfix/cleanup[25701]: 8FDABE20E93: message-id=<20200420102242.8FDABE20E93@igslt14-HP-Notebook>
Apr 20 15:52:42 igslt14-HP-Notebook postfix/qmgr[25695]: 8FDABE20E93: from=<igs-lt14@igslt14-HP-Notebook>, size=396, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 20 15:52:43 igslt14-HP-Notebook postfix/smtp[25703]: 8FDABE20E93: to=<sampleemail971@gmail.com>, relay=smtp.gmail.com[2404:6800:4003:c02::6c]:587, delay=0.83, delays=0.13/0.02/0.47/0.21, dsn=5.7.0, status=bounced (host smtp.gmail.com[2404:6800:4003:c02::6c] said: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. f21sm723614pfn.71 - gsmtp (in reply to MAIL FROM command))
Apr 20 15:52:43 igslt14-HP-Notebook postfix/cleanup[25701]: 960C3E20E94: message-id=<20200420102243.960C3E20E94@igslt14-HP-Notebook>
Apr 20 15:52:43 igslt14-HP-Notebook postfix/qmgr[25695]: 960C3E20E94: from=<>, size=2569, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 20 15:52:43 igslt14-HP-Notebook postfix/bounce[25704]: 8FDABE20E93: sender non-delivery notification: 960C3E20E94
Apr 20 15:52:43 igslt14-HP-Notebook postfix/qmgr[25695]: 8FDABE20E93: removed
Apr 20 15:52:43 igslt14-HP-Notebook postfix/local[25705]: 960C3E20E94: to=<igs-lt14@igslt14-HP-Notebook>, relay=local, delay=0.13, delays=0.05/0.02/0/0.06, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Apr 20 15:52:43 igslt14-HP-Notebook postfix/qmgr[25695]: 960C3E20E94: removed
```

this is the file to configure to send the mail to email.please let me know what changes have to be made to send the email.

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = igslt14-HP-Notebook
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = igslt14-HP-Notebook, igslt14-HP-Notebook, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
inet_protocols = all
```

Comment: Welcome, kishore. Please tag your files properly.

Comment: @Quasímodo i did not understand please explain

Comment: You tagged your question with "sed", but what does sed have to do with your question? "email", on the other hand, fits your question.

Comment: @Quasímodo please let me know what changes to be made to send email using postfix

Comment: Hi, have you got answer for your question?

Answer (score -1):

it seems your mails is bounced.

look at:

`Apr 20 15:52:43 igslt14-HP-Notebook postfix/smtp[25703]: 8FDABE20E93: to=<sampleemail971@gmail.com>, relay=smtp.gmail.com[2404:6800:4003:c02::6c]:587, delay=0.83, delays=0.13/0.02/0.47/0.21, dsn=5.7.0, status=**bounced** (host smtp.gmail.com[2404:6800:4003:c02::6c] said: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. f21sm723614pfn.71 - gsmtp (in reply to MAIL FROM command))`

Comment: so, may i know what is the solution?